# how to save a text file in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am doing a text editor program, but I am having trouble when saving the content from the text area to a .txt file. The content written does not show up. Instead a bunch of coding shows up.

Can anyone help me with this.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\Silvan\\Desktop"));
int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"))
    {
        fw.write(txt1.toString());
    }   
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you're not getting  the text of the `JTextArea` but in stead your saving the `JTextArea` it self

use :

```
fw.write(txt1.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd that comment was removed but from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) `getText()` is what you are looking for:

> Returns the text contained in this TextComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the JTextArea write() method:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( ... );
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( writer );
textArea.write( bw );
```